# E-mail sent from My Site Cleanup Job

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, my-site

I want to change the template of the e-mail sent from the My Site Cleanup Job.
I know the template is somewhere at ..\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14, but i cant find the template. Can someone help me?

I'm using sharepoint 2010

Thanks in advance